# Is it legal to dump data published on a site such as fifa for commercial purposes?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, data-ownership

I'm creating a mobile app where I need to display scores of football matches in real time and I was wondering if recovering these scores from Fifa website was legal.

Comment: What is the approach of other sites/apps that display such data? What is written in FIFA website about the data?

Comment: What country are you in?

Answer (score 1):

From FIFA's website terms:

> All FIFA Content, including FIFA feeds, is owned by, or licensed to,
>   FIFA. FIFA Content is provided to You “AS IS” and **may not be used**,
>   reproduced, distributed, transmitted, broadcast, displayed, sold,
>   licensed or otherwise exploited **for any other purposes than their
>   access and usage on the FIFA Digital Platforms**. For that sole and
>   exclusive purpose, FIFA grants to You a limited, revocable,
>   non-exclusive license to access and use the FIFA Digital Platforms
>   privately for non-commercial purposes, in accordance with these Terms.

There is a common law principle that facts do not enjoy copyright protection. However, the realtime display of data seems special because the presenter of the facts is going to some complicated lengths to make the display happen. While the compiler of the facts might not win a copyright case, they might ban you from their website and then use various property laws to make you liable if you keep pulling data from their sites.

Of course, there are other services that compile real time scores and they certainly have terms of use.